# What should I do when there is not enough memory to run my program in C?

Tags: c, memory, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I allocate a 2D array using double pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040496/how-can-i-allocate-a-2d-array-using-double-pointers)

I used VB 2012 Express to make a maze program.

It works really well even when I set `ROW*COLUMN` to `499*499`, (the maze is an array: `unsigned char maze[ROW][COLUMN]`).

But one time I tried to make a super-giant maze of`999*999`, and the compiler gave me a "stack overflow" error.

I do know what it means, but is there any way to assign extra memory or even use some disk space to run my program?

Comment: You're not out of memory. You're just out of stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating `maze` on the stack, and stack size is typically limited to between 1 and 8 megabytes. To overcome this limitation, allocate `maze` on the heap.

For suggestions on how to do this, see [How can I allocate a 2D array using double pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040496/how-can-i-allocate-a-2d-array-using-double-pointers) and [Heap allocate a 2D array (not array of pointers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116368/heap-allocate-a-2d-array-not-array-of-pointers)

Comment: thx. so what should i do to an object in a class?

Answer (score 2):

You can either dynamically allocate your array (e.g `maze = new char[ROW*COLUMN]`) or allocate it globally (outside function scope), like

```
#define ROW 999
#define COLUMN 999

unsigned char maze[ROW][COLUMN];

int main(void)
{

}
```